# Displaying Different Copy / Images Based on the Number of Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

We're working on developing a program that will (hopefully) automatically swap out creative with new creative once a certain like threshold is met (i.e. if 100 people like the page, something new appears). Can we add coding so our system is able to tell how many "likes" are generated? I know that the number of likes are displayed, I'm just not sure if there is a way for a program to actually read *how many* likes there are.

I don't see if in any of the Facebook attributes in the developer's platform.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll have to do is acquire an access token for your page and then query the facebook platform for the number of likes periodically (possibly with a cron job of sorts).
You can read more about how to get the page access token at this URL 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
Facebook has given us a great took to help us mine all the data it holds - its called the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and with it you can see what data will be returned when you query the API.  When you query the API with only the `page_id` you'll get a response similar to this :

```
{
  "id": "XXXXXXXXX", 
  "name": "My Awesome Page", 
  "picture": "foo.jpg", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/XXXXXXXX", 
  "likes": 345, 
  "category": "Product/service", 
  "website": "XXXXXXX", 
  "founded": "2011", 
  "description": "...", 
}
```

For more information about how to use the Graph API you can see this link :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does provide good documentation:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

As you can see there, there is a field "likes" containing the number (count) of likes for a page.